# Odd text truncation in NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts, storyboard, nstextfield

Take a look at the following selection from a window in my app:

[image]

Notice anything strange? Each one of the dashes is progressively smaller than the one above and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Each line ("11 -", "12 -", "13 -", etc) is an NSTextField within my storyboard, and each is right justified with the layout set to truncate — so I would think that if the text field is too short, truncation would occur at the left side of the text field, not on the left side of the rightmost character!

To extend the mystery, this seems to be happening when the font is set to Future Medium, not, say, Arial or Century.

Can anyone shed some light on what could be happening? I'm kind of baffled?!?!!

Comment: Is the width of the dash related to the width of the number? What is the untruncated string? What are the settings of Layout and Line Break?

Comment: In all cases I'm using the same dash character (an en dash), and the untruncated strings are exactly what you see in the picture: "11 -", "12 -", etc...  Line Break is set to "Clip" and Layout is "Truncates". I was able to work around the problem by widening the frame by several pixels, but I'm still curious as to why the truncation is occurring within the string and not on either side.

Comment: The string is clipped because the Line Break is "Clip".

Comment: But why does the clipping take place within the middle of the string? Maybe because it is trying to insure an ellipsis and just doesn't have room?

Comment: The clipping takes place on the right side of the string. The distance between the number and the dash is almost the same for all numbers in the image.